# Raspberry Pi 2 Raspbian WiFi Setup

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to follow [Setting WiFi up via the command line - Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) and missing getting `command not found` message. I assume I have to hook it up via cable to install that via `apt-get`, but which package do I need to install exactly?

"what i did" ;)

[Getting started with Docker on your Raspberry Pi · Docker Pirates ARMed with explosive stuff](http://blog.hypriot.com/getting-started-with-docker-on-your-arm-device/)

Comment: `wireless-tools`?

Comment: The reference you quoted says "note that no additional software is required; everything you need is already included on the Raspberry Pi". Tell us what YOU did, not what you were trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying `Hypriot Docker SD card image` (image is based on raspbian)

Comment: This appears to be some kind of webserver (which was not your original question), although I wasn't prepared to read through all the hype to figure out. You still haven't said what you did; i.e. what commands you actually typed.

Comment: My question is up-to-date now) I `dd` image, then boot it, logged in and fail to pass step `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` due to `command not found` message and to install whatever is missing, I'd need a ethernet cable and name of the package)